# template initiation benchmark phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, polymer, benchmarking, phonegap-build

I am working on a project in which I'm using Phonegap to build a hybrid app and google polymer for UI.

Recently I build my app using phonegap site not through CLI. After installing the app on phone I was unable to see any thing. Here is the screenshot which I'm seeing.
[image]

I tried running the benchmark but it runs for hours and nothing show next. I tested it only on Android not on iOS or Windows.

I'm really stuck on this. Please help me out. I tried enabling and disabling debugging and hydration in setting.

Answer (score 0):

@Micro Ice, if you are talking about [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/), the web components framework, then you should be aware that this [does NOT work on all platforms yet](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20components). Accordingly, from what *caniuse.com* says, you should set your *android:minSdkVersion* fairly high.

I set mine low, because I build for a wider audience. My code looks like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
```

Google: [android minSdkVersion](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20minSdkVersion)

This is your reference:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html